# Linux terminal SCREEN command

Tags: linux

I want to open a new terminal to execute a script file again. I need to open a new terminal and execute one more script.
I give a try with SCREEN command but it does work for only the first terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't open a new screen inside a screen. If you need another terminal inside the screen press "CTRL+a" and then "c".

This should open a new terminal. You can swap between terminals by "CTRL+a" followed by "a".

If you open more than two terminals inside the screen you can open an overview with "CTRL+a and then SHIFT+2"

If your done detatch the screen by pressing "CTRL+a then d". Reopen a screen with "screen -x (+ screen-id if you have multiple screens detatched)"

Comment: i need to open a second screen via script not manually.
screen -S start-ovs
./vswitchd/ovs-vswitchd unix:$DB_SOCK --pidfile
screen -dmS set-pmd
export OVS_UTIL_DIR=/root/openvswitch-2.7.0

Comment: Ok sorry, i get it now. So what happens with the second screen? Does it just get closed or is it dead?

Normally when you run a script or command in a screen, the screen terminates immediately after the script/command is done. Since you are just export something.

Comment: The second screen is not at all opening.I need to open the second screen without closing the first screen means i need to keep the execution that is already running on my screen 1.In screen, you can press ctrl+a c to create new terminal inside the same screen session. Now I have to automate this activity and do the same from my bash script .......